# 404 page not found for codeigniter MVC while front_end setup

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have searched for this but could not find any useful solution so I am posting my question here. I am using codeigniter MVC for my project. I have setup backend/admin panel nicely but for front-end part I am getting "404 page not found" error when I tried to setup front-end in codeigniter MVC.

My Application structure is:

```
project_name
--application
  controllers
    -- admin
    -- front_end
       -- Front_end.php
  models
    -- admin
    -- front_end
       -- Mdl_front_end.php
  views
    -- admin
    -- front_end
      -- home.php
```

routes.php

```
  $route['default_controller'] = 'front_end/front_end/index';
  $route['404_override'] = '';
  $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
  $route['admin'] = 'admin/login';
  $route['admin/gallery'] = 'admin/gallery/add';
  $route['about'] = 'front_end/about';
```

core/MY_Controller.php

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }
 }
?>
```

application/controllers/front_end/Front_end.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Front_end extends MY_Controller {

  public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }
  public function index(){
    $this->load->view('front_end/home');
  }
}
```

**whenever I access the root URL like: http://localhost/prject_name/ getting "404 Page Not Found" error**. Anyone please point me in right direction? Thanks.

Comment: try removing index from your default controller ie `$route['default_controller'] = 'front_end/front_end';`

Comment: route['default_controller'] = 'front_end/front_end/index'; is not a class. It should be route['default_controller'] = 'front_end/front_end'

Comment: I already tried without index as `front_end/front_end` but dint work. @sauhardnc @fraggley

Comment: `$route['default_controller'] = 'front_end';` and then open `http://localhost/project_name/front_end `. If you want it to open on only `http://localhost/project_name` then move the content of `front_end` folder directly into `controller` folder.

Comment: Why you didn't comeback to see the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Tow answers to this problem.

1. To work with CodeIgniter default settings for routes by using just controllers that resides on controllers folder directly `$route['default_controller'] = 'controllerName'`, by using this option there is no way to work with sub folders, for instance **controllers/subfolder/yourcontroller.php**. No way to do something like this `$route['default_controller'] = 'subfolder/yourcontroller';`. Fortunately we can manipulate CodeIgniter by create new route for every sub folder in the controllers folder to specify a default controller for that path. Lets see this in your project, you have `controllers/front_end/front_end.php`, so you have to go `application/config/routes.php` and add the following line:

   $route['front_end'] = 'front_end/front_end';

Then open the browser and write http://localhost/projectname/front_end, it is equivalent to http://localhost/projectname/front_end/front_end/index.

2. By overriding CodeIgniter router class by your own class, to do this add my_router.php file in the path `application/core`, inside that file copy and paste the following code:

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

protected function _set_default_controller() {

    if (empty($this->default_controller)) {

        show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
    }

    // Is the method being specified?
    if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
        $method = 'index';
    }

    // This is what I added, checks if the class is a directory

    if( is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class) ) {

        // Set the class as the directory

        $this->set_directory($class);

        // $method is the class

        $class = $method;

        // Re check for slash if method has been set

        if (sscanf($method, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
            $method = 'index';
        }
    }


    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php')) {

        // This will trigger 404 later

        return;
    }

    $this->set_class($class);
    $this->set_method($method);

    // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1

    $this->uri->rsegments = array(
        1 => $class,
        2 => $method
    );

    log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
}
}
```

After finishing this go to your application/config/routes.php and set up your default controller:

```
   $route['default_controller'] = 'front_end/fornt_end';
```

Then in your browser just type : http://localhost/projectname, and boom you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

ci3 is designed in this way 
you cannot set default controller in nested manner..

but if you still want to do that. you can do this way

set `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`

home.php should be in root path of controller `/controller/home.php`
and include your controller here

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

//requiring home controller
require_once APPPATH."controllers/front_end/Front_end.php";
```